# ArcGIS - OD matrix: Quality of results with a fragmented rail network

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, network-analyst

I have a question about the results of an OD-matrix. I have data of harbours (destination and origins) and want to determine the distance between them. I will use a road network. It seems that not all railroads are connected. However I still get a distance between these specific points.

Does anyone know how they are measured and if this is correct. The distance does not correspond with euclidean distance, so that is not what is happening if the tool can not find a rail connection.